# Как добавлять к списку какое-то значение в state`е в AIOgram 3.0.0b6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, асинхронность, aiogram-3.x

У меня проблема, я не могу понять, как прибавить что-то к списку в бета версии AIOgram`a.

В Aiogram 2 я делал так:

```
async def this_is_function(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        #data['list'].append(12345)
        # или:
        #data['int_value'] += 1
        #И так далее
```

Как подобное можно реализовать в бета версии Aiogram 3, ведь метода proxy в FSMContex там нет?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
async def some_func(m: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(your_msg=m.text)
```

Вот таким образом можно "добавить данные в стейт".
Чтобы получить значение, можно поступить следующим образом:

```
data = await state.get_data()
print(data['your_msg']
```

Comment: Вьі не поняли. Как получать данньіе я знаю. Во второй версии Aiogram меня очень вьіручал метод proxy, которьій в FSMContext. Я хотел узнать, можно ли возсоздать что-то подобное в третей версии Aiogram (тот код котрьій прикрепил), ведь метода proxy уже не наблюдаю.

Answer (score 0):

теперь пишу так:

async def cmd_get_dict_storage(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):

```
    data = await state.get_data()
    
    #ваш код работы со словарем "data"
    
    await state.set_data(data)
```